# How to make LinearLayout content scroll?

Tags: android

Im trying to scroll some content inside a linearlayout and the outer layout is as relativelayout that includes a header and a bottom menu.

How to make it scrollable ?

This is my current layout. But nothing happens in scrolling the linearlayout section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<include layout="@layout/header_guide"
    android:id="@+id/GuideHeaderInclude"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/GuideHeaderInclude"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/GuideContentHolder">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/guidecard"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideRegCardHeader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideRegCardText"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/guidemap"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideMapHeader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideMapText"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/guidelist"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideVerifyHeader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideVerifyText"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/guidecashback"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideCashbackHeader"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/GuideCashbackText"
    style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"
    android:id="@+id/GuideBottomMenu"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you have the `LinearLayout` can't the `TextView`s just be directly in the `ScrollView`?

Comment: did you tried adding scrollview on top of the relativeLayout ?

Comment: @Dreagen There is a reason Dreagan.  *ScrollView* can only have one item .  So it is typical to put it inside a layout.

Comment: @Darkie yeah, have tried to put i on top. Did not work.

Comment: I think you need to give weight to the scrollview. because two layout xmls are included. may be there is no space for scrollview.

Comment: @VikashKumar : he can't coz parent layout is a `RelativeLayout` and it doesn't allow `layout_weight` attribute

Comment: @VikashKumar Scrollview can't be given a weight because it is inside a relativelayout.

Comment: @farnholdt : is your `last` *TextView* is visible

Comment: @kaushik yes, it has some properties than the other textviews, so it is visible.

Comment: @farnholdt : every view inside `scrollable` area is visible. If not try to change the property(last textview) and give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include layout="@layout/header_guide"
        android:id="@+id/GuideHeaderInclude"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/GuideContentHolder">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/guidecard"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideRegCardHeader"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideRegCardText"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/guidemap"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideMapHeader"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideMapText"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/guidelist"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideVerifyHeader"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideVerifyText"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/guidecashback"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideCashbackHeader"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutHeaderStyle"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/GuideCashbackText"
                style="@style/OnlineAboutTextStyle"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"
        android:id="@+id/GuideBottomMenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```